# Optimizing Objective-c code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a block of code that I am trying to optimize. The method is being used a lot so any little improvement would greatly increase performance.

```
- (CGRect)calculateRectForItemAtIndex:(NSIndexPath*)path {
    //Get the x position stored in an NSMutableArray
    double x = [self.sectionXPlacementArray[path.section] doubleValue];
    double y = 0;
    double height = 0;

    //If this is the first row it is a header so treat it different 
    if (path.row == 0) {
        height = self.defaultHeaderHeight;
        y = 0;
    }
    else {
        height = self.defaultHeight;
        //Calculate the Y placement 
        y = (path.row-1)*self.defaultHeight+self.defaultHeaderHeight;
    }
    //Build and return a CGRect
    return CGRectMake(x, y, [self.headerSizes[self.headers[path.section]] doubleValue],height);
}
```

Here is some more information:

1) `headerSizes` is a `NSMutableDictionary` that looks like so:

```
{
    Header1 = 135;
    Header2 = 130;
    Header3 = 130;
}
```

2) `headers` is a `NSMutableArray` that looks like this:

```
(
    Header1,
    Header2,
    Header3
)
```

These values in the app will not be Header_. They will be dynamic NSStrings like "City" or "State". `headerSizes` will contain the width that should be used for each header.

Comment: Are you sure that this method is actually slowing your app down?

Comment: no way this is going your bottleneck

Comment: Performance bottlenecks aren't apparent in your example.  But, I am curious - this looks remarkably like a table.  That being said, if performance is your concern, use a UITableView instead.  Apple has all sorts of experience with this type of thing such as queueing cells and whatnot.

Comment: This is used in a very customized collectionView with unique placements and requirements. A UITableView would not would.

Comment: The way to demonstrate whether this is the problem is to simplify the code down to a constant return (just return the same value every time). It will never be faster than that, so if returning a constant doesn't improve your performance, then optimizing this code is unhelpful.

Comment: I see @Jaybit.  I suppose I was thrown off by headers and rows.  Perhaps a UICollectionView would be more suitable since it's specialty is, in fact, to display a collection of data in a customizable manner; though, that's neither here nor there.  The general consensus seems to be that there is no performance issue with your code, at least nothing worth writing home about.  Please explain to the readers why you feel there is a performance problem.  Perhaps there is a bigger issue at play, such as a long running task on the main thread causing your view to appear as though it were slow.

Comment: ...or else your question will fall by the wayside as this, in its current form, is pretty broad.

Comment: I understand that this code is very simplistic and does not seem like a bottleneck. All I am asking here is if there are any minor improvements that can be done to optimize it. If you don't have any improvements fine. If you do Please let me know.

Comment: I suppose if you are caching `sectionXPlacementArray`, `headerSizes`, and `headers` you might get a slight improvement, but nothing noticeable.  Other than that, you will be happy (or dissapointed?) to know that your code is fine.

Comment: I spent some time simplifying and stripping it down. I got an ok performance improvement from what I did. I wanted to check to see if I missed anything. There were some good suggestions. Use float instead of double, and const NSUInteger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As another person commented, this does NOT look like a method that would be slowing anything down. It's involved in laying something out, right? Or drawing something? That should not be happening very often (i.e. 60 times per second at *worst*). Do you actually have any **evidence** that this is the bottleneck? Like, have you run your code through the Profiler template in Instruments? And this showed up as the #1 top method in an inverted-call-tree view of the data?

That said, there's not much to pare down here.  I did my best...

```
- (CGRect)calculateRectForItemAtIndex:(NSIndexPath*)path
{
    //Get the x position stored in an NSMutableArray
    const NSUInteger pathSection = path.section;
    const NSUInteger pathRow = path.row;
    const float x = [self.sectionXPlacementArray[pathSection] floatValue];
    float y = 0;
    float height = 0;

    //If this is the first row it is a header so treat it different
    if (pathRow == 0) {
        height = self.defaultHeaderHeight;
        y = 0;
    }
    else {
        const float defaultHeight = self.defaultHeight;
        height = defaultHeight;
        //Calculate the Y placement
        y = (pathRow-1)*defaultHeight+self.defaultHeaderHeight;
    }
    //Build and return a CGRect
    return CGRectMake(x, y, [self.headerSizes[self.headers[pathSection]] floatValue], height);
}
```

Comment: well, using floats instead of doubles should be an improvement with almost no precision lost.

Comment: I would expect that difference to be marginal, but then again, this whole question/answer is kinda bogus, 'cause there is *no way* that this method is the bottleneck, and if it is, then whatever's calling it is "doin' it wrong." (PS: I guess on ARM the penalty for double may be higher than x86_64. Don't feel like disassembling it and counting instructions and cycles. :) )

Comment: I definitely agree. My comment would be valid only on codereview.stackexchange :) It's just strange to use `double` where every type is defined as `CGFloat`.

Comment: Force of habit... I spend a lot of time in OSX where `CGFloat` is defined as `double`, and doing other stuff where FP precision matters (groan).

Comment: So why not declare them CGFloat and not have to worry which it is?

Comment: One could possibly construct the CGRect manually vs calling CGRectMake and save a smidgen.

Comment: CGRectMake is marked for inlining. I would generally expect the compiler to have already made that optimization for me.

Comment: As for using CGFloat, there's not (by default) framework support for a `-[NSNumber CGFloatValue]` so not having to worry potentially hides two conversions. But really, we're splitting hairs here.